# is there anyway I can swap the year and day value in sql?

Tags: mysql, database

i tried to load my data and somehow the column with date type date has swaped the value of year to day and day to year. is there any way i can swap them?

output

```
+------------+
| deadline   |
+------------+
| 2029-05-14 |
| 2019-01-18 |
| 2016-02-01 |
| 2023-10-14 |
| 2025-03-16 |
 +------------+
```

also I loaded the data as dd-mm-yy format.

Comment: What type is `deadline`?

Comment: @Dishant: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51769224/2469308   if it works please upvote and accept as answer :)

Comment: @mureinik its date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to display dates in whatever way you please. E.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(deadline, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SUBSTR](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php) function, to get month and day parts out of the `deadline` field, and then use [CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php) function to join them back again in different order.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET deadline = CONCAT(SUBSTR(deadline, 1, 5), 
                      SUBSTR(deadline, 9, 2), 
                      '-', 
                      SUBSTR(deadline, 6, 2) 
                     )
WHERE 1 = 1
```